# Conver country name to lowercase

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, openweathermap

I am trying to get the country flag icon of Open Weather Map API:
Example: http://openweathermap.org/images/flags/br.png

The country code json that's returned from api request is in upper case,
to get the right icon of country I need the same country code but in lower case

and this what I tried :

```
<img src="http://openweathermap.org/images/flags/{{lowerCase(weather.sys.country)}}.png">
```

Comment: you can use the angular [LowerCasePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is [toLowerCase](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) and it is a string function.

```
<img src="http://openweathermap.org/images/flags/{{weather.sys.country.toLowerCase()}}.png">
```

Comment: I try and return the same err: https://i.ibb.co/frx2wqM/Screenshot-from-2019-06-02-09-30-42.png